# How to insert complex models in a sqlite table?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, windows-store-apps

First of all I should apologize if the question doesn't seem a pro one however I have no idea how to deal with it.

I actually have a Person class in which there are another class namely Address and the Address class itself have properties whose types are another class namely Province and City.

```
public class Province
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Province Province { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public Address { get; set; }

}
```

I should say I used to work with Mongodb and as many of you may know with Mongodb you can insert , update and delete the document itself . But now the company which I'm working for is moving to windows store applications and it appears that it doesn't work with Mongodb so I've decided to use Sqlite instead however, as I said earlier I have really have no idea how to design the tables so that I can read and write my person objects into them.

So I need your help very badly. please put me in the right path. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

SQLLite is much similar to the normal SQL database but some cutdown on complex functionalities, you can create a persons table with all the fields (which are the class properties) and insert it into the table, and select the data accordingly whenever necessary

Comment: Sorry I think I misunderstand you. do you mean that I can store an Address object in the SQlite field?

Comment: No, basically you need to create fields for each property, for e.g. in person table you need to add fields like, Id (int), Name (Varchar), Phone (varchar), Province {varchar) , City(varchar), Street(varchar), PostalCode(varchar)

Comment: So to retrieve the person details, you need to do a select statement and assign the result to the corresponding property of the object and return the object

Comment: ok. what if I want to have two or more addresses? for example HomeAddress and WorkAddress?

Comment: in that case you can create a separate address table, and refer the person id (which i suppose be the primary key in person table) and use it as the foreign key in address table

Answer (score -3):

This is *not* a website where you can come to learn how to use a database, as that is far too broad in scope for anyone to cover. But in short, you would essentially need to set up your database tables in the same way that you have designed your classes.

The only exception is that rather than the `Person` table having an `Address` object, it would have an `AddressId` column that relates to the `Id` column that you need to add to the `Address` table. Likewise, rather than the `Address` table having an `City` object, it would have an `CityId` column that relates to the `Id` column that you need to add to the `City` table.

So each table should have its own uniquely identifiable `Id` column and the `Id` values are used a foreign keys in other tables, as noted above. It's only in code that we build this flat model up into a hierarchical one. Now really I should have voted to close this question for being off topic... please don't make me regret this decision by asking me loads of follow up questions. I cannot answer all your database queries.