# how to save custom object into sqlite database on windows phone8 using c#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sqlite

how to save custom object into sqlite database on windows phone8  using c#?

```
public class Person
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }


        public string Name { get; set; }


        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public List<Address> Items { get; set; }

        public List<SubAddress> Subaddress { get; set; }

    }
    public class Address
    {
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public string pin { get; set; }
        public List<SubAddress> Subaddress { get; set; }
    }
    public class SubAddress
    {
        public string SubAddresscity { get; set; }
        public string SubAddressstate { get; set; }
        public string SubAddresspin { get; set; }
    }




     Person person = new Person
            {
                Name = "Matteo",
                Surname = "Pagani",
                Items = new List<Address> 
                { 
                    new Address 
                    { 
                        city="fdsdf",state="sfds",pin="dsfsd",Subaddress=new List<SubAddress>
                        {
                            new SubAddress
                            {
                                SubAddresscity="llll",
                                SubAddressstate="ffff",
                                SubAddresspin="gggg"
                            },
                             new SubAddress
                            {
                                SubAddresscity="llll",
                                SubAddressstate="ffff",
                                SubAddresspin="gggg"
                            },
                             new SubAddress
                            {
                                SubAddresscity="llll",
                                SubAddressstate="ffff",
                                SubAddresspin="gggg"
                            }
                        },

                    },                    
                    new Address
                    {
                        city="fdsdf",state="sfds",pin="dsfsd",Subaddress=new List<SubAddress>
                        {
                             new SubAddress
                            {
                                SubAddresscity="llll",
                                SubAddressstate="ffff",
                                SubAddresspin="gggg"
                            },
                             new SubAddress
                            {
                                SubAddresscity="llll",
                                SubAddressstate="ffff",
                                SubAddresspin="gggg"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Address
                    {
                        city="fdsdf",state="sfds",pin="dsfsd",Subaddress=new List<SubAddress>
                        {
                             new SubAddress
                            {
                                SubAddresscity="llll",
                                SubAddressstate="ffff",
                                SubAddresspin="gggg"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Address
                    {
                        city="fdsdf",state="sfds",pin="dsfsd",Subaddress=new List<SubAddress>
                        {                            
                        }
                    }
                },
                Subaddress = new List<SubAddress>
                {
                             new SubAddress
                            {
                                SubAddresscity="llll",
                                SubAddressstate="ffff",
                                SubAddresspin="gggg"
                            },
                             new SubAddress
                            {
                                SubAddresscity="llll",
                                SubAddressstate="ffff",
                                SubAddresspin="gggg"
                            },
                             new SubAddress
                            {
                                SubAddresscity="llll",
                                SubAddressstate="ffff",
                                SubAddresspin="gggg"
                            },
                             new SubAddress
                            {
                                SubAddresscity="llll",
                                SubAddressstate="ffff",
                                SubAddresspin="gggg"
                            }
                }

            };
```

how to save person  object directly into database and how to retrieve object ?

is it possible or not is possible can you please help me to achieve .

thanks ......

Comment: why down vote if you know ans give to me ..question is correct..once try it .

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad. At first, you should learn - [how to store objects in tables](http://bsubramanyamraju.blogspot.ru/2014/08/windowsphone-8-sqlite-storing-data-in.html). Then, how to [store complex objects in tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624768/how-to-insert-complex-models-in-a-sqlite-table) etc. It's impossible to answer with a few lines of text. Even general understanding of SQL databases is required.

Comment: thanks for your reply i worked lot of things on SQLite. It is possible ti give just i was asking some points.Any way thanks for your reply i achieve this task.